# Preventing unnecessary rendering with React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have a very basic application to test how to prevent unnecessary rendering, but I'm very confused as it is not working no matter what I try. Please take a look.

**App.js**

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import User from "./User";

let lastId = 0;

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    { id: 0, name: "Nicole Kidman", gender: "Female" },
  ]);

  const handleUserChange = useCallback(
    (e, userId) => {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      const newUsers = [...users];
      const index = newUsers.findIndex((user) => user.id === userId);
      if (index >= 0) {
        newUsers[index] = {
          ...newUsers[index],
          [name]: value,
        };
        setUsers(newUsers);
      }
    },
    [users]
  );

  const addNewUser = useCallback(() => {
    let newUser = { id: ++lastId, name: "John Doe", gender: "Male" };
    setUsers((prevUsers) => [...prevUsers, newUser]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={addNewUser}>Add user</button>
      <br />

      {users.map((user) => (
        <User key={user.id} user={user} handleUserChange={handleUserChange} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**User.js**

```
import { useRef, memo } from "react";

const User = memo(({ user, handleUserChange }) => {
  const renderNum = useRef(0);

  return (
    <div className="user">
      <div> Rendered: {renderNum.current++} times</div>

      <div>ID: {user.id}</div>
      <div>
        Name:{" "}
        <input
          name="name"
          value={user.name}
          onChange={(e) => handleUserChange(e, user.id)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        Gender:{" "}
        <input
          name="gender"
          value={user.gender}
          onChange={(e) => handleUserChange(e, user.id)}
        />
      </div>
      <br />
    </div>
  );
});

export default User;
```

Why the useCallback and memo doesn't do the job here? How can I make it work, prevent rendering of other User components if another User component is changing(typing something in Input)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useCallback and useMemo take a dependency array. If any of the values inside that array changes, React will re-create the memo-ized value/callback.

With this in mind, we see that your `handleUsersChange` useCallback is recreated every time the array `users` changes. Since you update the `users` state inside the callback, every time you call `handleUsersChange`, the callback is re-created, and therefore the child is re-rendered.

Solution:

Don't put `users` in the dependency array. You can instead access the `users` value inside the `handleUsersChange` callback by providing a callback to setUsers functions, like so:

```
const handleUserChange = useCallback(
(e, userId) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setUsers((oldUsers) => {
      const newUsers = [...oldUsers];
      const index = newUsers.findIndex((user) => user.id === userId);
      if (index >= 0) {
        newUsers[index] = {
          ...newUsers[index],
          [name]: value,
        };
        return newUsers;
      }
      return oldUsers;
  })
},
[]
```

);